# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel - How to add a range from one cell to another cell?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop

[image: screenshot]

As shown in the picture, say I have created a worksheet. How to select range cell2 to cell8 ?
I tried `worksheet.Range[lastRow.Cells[2], lastRow.Cells[8]]`, but it doesn't give me the expected result. Instead, it returns the grey area. What's the correct way of selecting it?

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: worksheet.Range(cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row,2), cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row),8))

Comment: range of cells 1 to cells 2. cells 1 = lastrow in column B, cells 2 = lastrow in colun G